# Elevation of status bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

**using safeArea like this**

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Payment Method"),
    centerTitle: true,
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.navigate_before,
        size: 40,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
    ),
  ),
        body: RefreshIndicator(
          -----)
```

**i am using this for status bar**

```
     void main() {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
    systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));runApp(MyApp());}
```

**but now what happens is appbar and statusbar seems seperated due to elevation of app bar so what can be best fix so that app bar and statusbar seems merged**

Comment: Did you tried add `elevation: 0` to AppBar ?

Comment: actually i need elevation in appbar

Comment: @TarunJain Can you share the screenshot ?

Answer (score 3):

**Implementing your code on Counter App.**

```
  void main() {
      SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.transparent,
      ));
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
```

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(widget.title),
              elevation: 10,
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '$_counter',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: _incrementCounter,
              tooltip: 'Increment',
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

**This is what I get implementing your the code in Counter App.**

Indeed the status bar and AppBar looks separated when you're using `SafeArea`.

[image]

**A very simple fix to this is :**

Change your `statusBarColor` like this :

```
statusBarColor: Colors.blue,
```

Also remove Debug Banner in `MaterialApp` adding this:

```
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
```

**Now the Counter App looks like this :**

[image]

After these small changes the StatusBar and AppBar doesn't looks separated.